# Building SWipe Application

Tags: c++, git, macos, qt, qmake

I'm currently trying to build this application https://github.com/ieatlint/SWipe on macOS and am not having any luck. I don't know much about building applications but this is what I have done so far.

```
git clone https://github.com/ieatlint/SWipe
cd SWipe
qmake SWipe.pro
make
```

And that's where I get an error:

```
make
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++ -c -pipe -stdlib=libc++ -O2 -std=gnu++11  -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.12.sdk -mmacosx-version-min=10.10 -Wall -W -fPIC -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_MULTIMEDIA_LIB -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_NETWORK_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I. -I/usr/local/Cellar/qt/5.9.1/lib/QtMultimedia.framework/Headers -I/usr/local/Cellar/qt/5.9.1/lib/QtWidgets.framework/Headers -I/usr/local/Cellar/qt/5.9.1/lib/QtGui.framework/Headers -I/usr/local/Cellar/qt/5.9.1/lib/QtNetwork.framework/Headers -I/usr/local/Cellar/qt/5.9.1/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers -I. -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.12.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Headers -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.12.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/AGL.framework/Headers -I/usr/local/Cellar/qt/5.9.1/mkspecs/macx-clang -F/usr/local/Cellar/qt/5.9.1/lib -o main.o main.cpp
main.cpp:1:10: fatal error: 'QtGui/QApplication' file not found
#include <QtGui/QApplication>
     ^
1 error generated.
make: *** [main.o] Error 1
```

I tried adding `QT += widgets` to the `SWipe.pro` file by using `sudo nano SWipe.pro` and adding it under where it says `QT += core gui multimedia`, but that didn't work.

Comment: Just `<QApplication>`.

Answer (score 0):

I just cloned it quickly and had a look. Here is what's wrong with the code:

- add widgets to the pro file as you already did (run qmake after this again)
- in main.cpp change the include from QtGui/QApplication to just Application (as suggested by AlexanderVX)
- Do the same in swipe.h for QtGui/QMainWindow and change it to just QMainWindow
- in swipe.cpp change audioFormat.setFrequency( 48000 ) to audioFormat.setSampleRate( 48000 ), assuming that is what it should do as there is no setFrequency function
- in swipe.cpp change audioFormat.setChannels( 1 ) to audioFormat.setChannelCount( 1 ), assuming that is what it should do as there is no setChannels function

I did this on my Mac and it builds this way. Have not run it though as I have not really looked into what this thing is doing... that's your job now I guess